# Jmeter Spike Testing

Tags: jmeter

I am literally new to Jmeter and have just started exploring the tool. I am developing tests to perform load and stress test on a website where the peak load is 10000 users an hour. The stats are something like:

Hour 
Index Users
0   2,728
1   1,656
2   1,123
3   1,058
4   1,174
5   1,710
6   3,524
7   5,808
8   7,505
9   8,432
10  9,113
11  9,577
12  9,814
13  9,674
14  10,028
15  9,781
16  8,445
17  8,156
18  6,193
19  6,175
20  5,922
21  5,641
22  4,694
23  3,068

I want to use the ramp up and ramp down feature along with Spike in load but unsure which thread group should i use? The Ultimate Thread group or the Stepping Thread group. Also unsure of how should i configure these thread groups. Any pointers would be greatly helpful.

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Stepping Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/) documentation

> This plugin is deprecated and should not be used. Use [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) instead.

So Stepping Thread Group doesn't come into play.

Now you need to make a choice between Ultimate Thread Group and Concurrency Thread Group which should be simple as:

- Ultimate Thread Group is about **threads** (or virtual users) which seems to be more applicable for your case
- Concurrency Thread Group is about **concurrency** (or requests per second) which is very useful when you need to generate certain **throughput** in terms of hits per second rather than need to mimic certain amount of virtual users.

So I would go for the Ultimate Thread Group. With regards to "how to configure" - just use the above values as they are, example configuration for first 8 hours would be something like:

[image: JMeter Ultimate Thread Group Workload]

You can install Ultimate Thread Group using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager).

Comment: Thanks a ton @Dmitri T. This helps a lot. But what i was wondering is that this data keeps on changing daily. So i may not be able to hardcode these values directly into the thread group. Whats the best option then?

Comment: You  can define the values which a changing as [JMeter Properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) via [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)  like `${__P(hour0)}` and either pass the values individually like `jmeter -Jhour0=2728 -Jhour1=1656...`  or in bulk using `-q` [command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for the response. But will it be possible to elaborate this further?